# pdf.js error in IE11, src property (0x800a138f)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, pdf.js

My app displays pdfs using pdf.js. Everything works fine, but of course IE does not. It throws an exception while starting:

```
Unhandled exception at line 8290, column 5 in http://.../scripts/pdf-js/pdf.js

0x800a138f - Timeout execution error JavaScript Code: Couldn't load(get) "src" property fo undefined or empty call.
```

Everything works fine with rendering pdf, I would just like to get rid of this exception.
(Please note that I was translating the error message that comes after "0x800a138f". If someone knows exact english error content I'll change it and the questions title).

**UPDATE**
Error occurs with each application start. As I said, everything works just fine. The lines of the pdf.js script where exception bumps:

```
if (!PDFJS.workerSrc && typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  // workerSrc is not set -- using last script url to define default location
 PDFJS.workerSrc = (function () {
    'use strict';
     var pdfJsSrc = document.currentScript.src; // here the src cannot be found
     return pdfJsSrc && pdfJsSrc.replace(/\.js$/i, '.worker.js');
   })();
}
```

Comment: No such error at http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html . Please provide more information and steps to reproduce the issue. As is this question is not addressable.

Comment: I updated the question with exact code where IE finds an exception. I am not sure about the steps to reproduce since it happens on application start.

Comment: Wha application you are referring to?

Comment: it is a .NET MVC application with Angular written in Typescript managing UI behavior. There is no such issue with Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Include compatibility.js to fix the errors on IE11.

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/compatibility.js

```
<script src="compatibility.js"></script>
```

compatibility.js implements any missing functionality required by PDFJS.

This also fixes other bugs such as some pdfs not loading on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this issue was quite simple although I don't know how safe.In my specific case pdf viewing works well after I added another condition:

```
if (!PDFJS.workerSrc && typeof document !== 'undefined' && typeof document.currentScript !== 'undefined' ) {
  // workerSrc is not set -- using last script url to define default location
  PDFJS.workerSrc = (function () {
  'use strict';
   var pdfJsSrc = document.currentScript.src;
   return pdfJsSrc && pdfJsSrc.replace(/\.js$/i, '.worker.js');
   })();
}
```

Comment: PDF.js polyfills document.currentScript in web/compatibility.js file. See https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-browsers-are-supported